# How to exclude projects from import when using wildcard with msbuild import

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have a top level msbuildproj `foo.csproj`. In this project I have the line

```
<Import "**\*.props"/>
```

However this includes the `bin` directory which is at the same level as the project file. I have tried

```
<Import Project="**\*.props" Exclude="obj;bin" />
<Import Project="**\*.targets" Exclude="obj;bin" />
```

Is there a way to solve this

but I get

[image]